# Android - Lightweight solution for image video watermarking

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, watermark, video-watermarking

How to add image on video **not** using ffmpeg but using some another approach? What more lightweight solutions exists for simple putting image on video?

I know few apps with this functionality that have very small size. What approach do they use?

1. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ashimpd.watermark
2. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jcom.watermark.video

Comment: Why not ffmpeg ? This might help if you reconsider ffmpeg
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358489/adding-watermark-bitmap-over-video-in-android-4-3s-mediamuxer-or-ffmpeg .

Comment: Because ffmpeg has many functions and relatively very big size. I need only watermark - little addition to my app, and I'm searching lightweight solution.

Comment: @mtwain any luck with that?

Comment: @MateusGondim only via OpenGL camera preview rendering.

Comment: @mtwain could you answer this question explaining your approach with more details? I'm also looking for a lightweight solution for this.