# Record video with text/image over camera(Surface view or Texture view)

Tags: android, video-capture

I m working on a project, where I need to record video from camera. At the time of recording we are showing some text over screen. But we are not able to record that text along with preview part. Is this posible to record both.

I am using https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video example to record video.

Please help.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't think that's possible. You can fetch video frames from a camera preview, but there's no good way to encode them back to video. The MediaRecorder can only record the actual direct camera input into a video file.

I will suggest you to look at [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) and [MediaMuxer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html)

Also, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358489) if you can use ffmpeg.