# Android Adding Watermark to video

Tags: android, video-processing

I used [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) project for making video recording app. Now i want to add watermark to the video.(I have filepath for video). Please Someone help with any code snippet or suggestion. And yeah **i don't want to use ffmpeg like heavy library unless no other solution is left**.

Such Similar question exist but didn't find any solution.
Here a solution is posted but it's not clear exactly how to proceed:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43231245/7026525 Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This project may be useful for you https://github.com/ksvc/KSYMediaEditorKit_Android

Comment: @snehadesai can you please tell how, i didn't get anything from project, or can you share code snippet if you have any.

Comment: In this project you have to see the RecordActivity.java file in which they are added watermark on video.

Comment: I checked the project they are using ffmpeg, see inside libs.

Comment: Did you find any solution @RishabhChandel

Comment: @HassanUsman at the end I used ffmpeg only.

Comment: @RishabhChandel Can you share your code snippet to add the watermark to the video?

Comment: @nmanikumar5 I don't have that code anymore!

Comment: @RishabhChandel OMG 
Can anyone have it?
Please do share

Comment: Any solution for this? @nmanikumar5

Comment: @ShylendraMadda no,
Please share if anyone have it