# How to Edit and add Watermark or Text in a video with help of MediaCodec

Tags: android, mp4, android-video-player, android-mediacodec, android-textureview

How to add a textView or Watermark[Images] in a video . So that i can Overlay this bitmap at the bottom of the video on all frames and save the video on extarnal storage . After some search i found that there some helpful ways to do it which are ffmpeg and MediCodec but i choose to go with MediaCodec after some good Points in it . I found this library to edit the videos which was lot helpful https://github.com/natario1/Transcoder. But couldn't find any helpful source for adding TextView. Found this Question which was already asked and 5 years old [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358489/adding-watermark-bitmap-over-video-in-android-4-3s-mediamuxer-or-ffmpeg) here Where this project was sounds a lot features are there https://github.com/google/grafika but i couldn't move forward with it I don't where to start as new to android it would be great if someone suggest me some good links or any hints how the process of video editing works i.e adding image or text in the frame and is there any simple new advanced ways do it now.Java links much appreciated Thanks

[image]